# JasperReports: Export a xls/ods file with formulas

Tags: excel-formula, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

Recently, I had to export some reports using JasperReports under ods /xls format.

The export works fine but I didn't manage to find a way to add some excel formulas between the exported columns (let's simplify it by saying a sum of some columns as described below).

[image: Screenshot]

When user modifies the column A in the excel file, column C gets modified (basic excel formulas, nothing new...)

Based on some comments and answers here is what I've done

```
<detail>
<band height="134" splitType="Stretch">
    <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="120" height="60" uuid="884b6c49-9006-464d-982e-e2a5f2cb3e3e">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Empty Dataset1" uuid="b60c3bee-0624-4a6a-bbb1-e706521c0a9a">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Arrays.asList($F{dto}.getNbLgtA()))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="40" uuid="1dbb56d0-f25f-410b-9e02-d08b7fe84388">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne1"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="ff8f394e-39ea-4d08-898f-601e92e6d1f3"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="c0c2b023-2d00-4080-88a3-a73f19fe9cda"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="40" uuid="33f41b08-3d77-4076-9712-9514211dd3af">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne2"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="ad2b74aa-95bf-43d7-83a4-6528f344b410"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[B]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="6d121f9e-e92d-45ba-9a48-82bf8b1245e0"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[2]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="40" uuid="42d367d1-2be7-46bf-838b-ba4c1c6f3399">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne3"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="63e3dd54-0297-463f-b061-4c536baf62a8"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[C]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula" value="SUM(A2, B2)"/>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add your code and templates with your question for exactly understanding your question

Comment: @New-Learner question edited

Comment: @Mitchapp Yes, it is possible to use formula. You can look at [Exporting XLS Formulas](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsformula/index.html#xlsformula)

Comment: @AlexK actually I'm using Jaspersoft studio version 6.1.1, and when I add  a simple `<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula"><![CDATA[SUM(D2,E2)]]></propertyExpression>` compilation fails with "D2 cannot be resolved to a variable"..

Comment: @Mitchapp As per Alex comment You can use formula like <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula" value="SUM(A2,A3)"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you could find some useful information about using Excel formulas:
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsformula/index.html#xlsformula

For instance, below is an example of using SUM formula (the expression should be enclosed within quotes):

```
    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula">
    <![CDATA["SUM(A1,B1)"]]>
    </propertyExpression>
```

You need to ensure that isDetectCellType property is set to true for your report in order to make a formula to work.
A complete working example (using an empty datasource) is the following:

```
    <detail>
    <band height="134" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="120" height="60" uuid="884b6c49-9006-464d-982e-e2a5f2cb3e3e">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Empty Dataset1" uuid="b60c3bee-0624-4a6a-bbb1-e706521c0a9a">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="40" uuid="1dbb56d0-f25f-410b-9e02-d08b7fe84388">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne1"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="ff8f394e-39ea-4d08-898f-601e92e6d1f3"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30">
                        <textField pattern="">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="b989d9e8-64d8-467f-a8a0-7b92a1746a0d"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[1]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="40" uuid="33f41b08-3d77-4076-9712-9514211dd3af">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne2"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="ad2b74aa-95bf-43d7-83a4-6528f344b410"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[B]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30">
                        <textField pattern="">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="3448c5dc-f887-415d-9833-4a22ea5b06c8"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[2]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="40" uuid="42d367d1-2be7-46bf-838b-ba4c1c6f3399">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Colonne3"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="63e3dd54-0297-463f-b061-4c536baf62a8"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[C]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell height="30">
                        <textField pattern="">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="63e3ed54-0567-463f-b0c1-4c676baf62a8">
                                <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula"><![CDATA["SUM(A" +($V{PAGE_COUNT}+2) + ",B" + ($V{PAGE_COUNT}+2) +")"]]></propertyExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[3]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: the size of the table is variable, so the formula has to be dynamic, how would you do that ?

Comment: The <propertyExpression /> element allows dynamic expressions. So, depending on your needs, you could write dynamic formulas, such as: <![CDATA["SUM(A" +$V{PAGE_COUNT} + ",B" + $V{PAGE_COUNT} +")"]]> that will apply for each consecutive row.

Comment: I've edited my question (added source code), and still don't manage to make the formula works. Any suggests ?

Comment: @Mitchapp: the formula property should be used within a <reportElement> in order to be considered. You could use a static text (or better a textfield) there, like in the below example:

Comment: `<jr:detailCell height="30">
  <staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="63e3ed54-0567-463f-b0c1-4c676baf62a8">
      <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula">
        <![CDATA["SUM(A" +($V{PAGE_COUNT}+1) + ",B" + ($V{PAGE_COUNT}+1) +")"]]>
      </propertyExpression>                            
    </reportElement>
    <text><![CDATA[3]]></text>
  </staticText>
</jr:detailCell>`

Comment: Would you post a full example ? (I've tried what you said but it didn't work)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112376/discussion-between-shertage-and-mitchapp).